# Difference between com.lowagie.text and iText 2.1.7 JAR?

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports, itext, birt

First of all, this is NOT a duplicate of this question: [What is the difference between lowagie and iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515210/what-is-the-difference-between-lowagie-and-itext)　 In this question, I'm only referring to the version used by both Jasper and BIRT, that is the 2.1.7.

What is the difference between BIRT's com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar and Jasper Reports' iText-2.1.7.jar?

I have been trying to integrate BIRT and Jasper Reports in my application and decide later which should I use. BIRT 4.6 uses com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar, while Jasper Reports 6.3 requires iText-2.1.7.jar. The framework I'm using for my application already has a MPL licensed iText-2.1.2.jar in it.

If I use BIRT and include com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar in my app's library, it works perfectly fine. However, if I use Jasper and include iText-2.1.7.jar it doesn't work well since it directs to the older iText-2.1.2.jar which lacks some function(setTabs() in PdfWriter). I have to delete the pre-existing iText-2.1.2 from the framework in order for Jasper Reports to work.

In what way did com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar differ from iText-2.1.7.jar for it to work without causing a conflict with the iText-2.1.2.jar?

Comment: `What is the difference between com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar and iText-2.1.7.jar?`, `First of all, this is NOT a duplicate of this question` - Why it is not a duplicate of [What is the difference between lowagie and iText?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13515210/876298) post?

Comment: I am the Lowagie you refer to when you talk about `com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar`, but even I don't know the answer to your question. I hope you now understand my frustration with people who use unofficial forks of iText that, sometimes illegally, (ab)use my name. This question may not be a duplicate of "What is the difference", but the following question certainly tells you what to do: [Can iText 2.1.7 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially) Stop using those old versions!

Comment: Where did you download your jars?

Comment: I upvoted @AlexK's comment because the OP does not explain why their question is not a duplicate. Their question may have different wording but the answer (given by Bruno in the comment above) essentially boils down to the same.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I understand the difference in versions 2.1.7(com.lowagie, MPL/LGPL) and 5.0.0(com.itext, AGPL). In this question, I'm only referring to the version used by both Jasper and BIRT, that is the 2.1.7. The JARs are included in Jasper and BIRT install packages. Jasper has since downgraded its iText version and BIRT has not upgraded theirs either. Since I'm trying to integrate either one of then I have to stick with the old version of iText.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I can only guess - one of the BIRT maintainers should answer this!

However, looking inside the "about_files" directory inside com.lowagie.text_2.1.7.v201004222200.jar delivery with BIRT 4.3.0 (it's probably basically the same with BIRT 4.6.0), you'll find the file "misc_licencses.txt".

As far as I understand it (but I'm not really sure), BIRT's version of iText 2.1.7 is identical to the original iText 2.1.7, with some bug fixes for code not written by Bruno Lowagie.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response! I looked into the file and indeed BIRT may have modified and added some tweaks to the iText 2.1.7. I also compared both JARs and BIRT's version contains some additional packages! I hope to hear some explanation from the BIRT team.