# What is the Difference between ITEXT and ITEXTPDF?

Tags: java, jar, itext

I am trying to migrate my **iText** dependency to a higher version. Before I used `itextpdf-5.4.2.jar` and `itext-1.3.1.jar`. Now I have migrated to `itextpdf-5.5.10.jar` and `itext-4.2.1.jar`.

After this upgrade, my PDF no longer prints barcodes. Barcodes worked perfectly with the earlier versions.

1. Is there anything I am missing regarding this jar migration?
2. What is the difference between these two jars?

My BarCode sample code:

```
Barcode39 code128 = new Barcode39();            
code128.setGenerateChecksum(true);            
code128.setCode(Id);  
code128.setBarHeight(50.0f);
code128.setX(30.0f);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between lowagie and iText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515210/what-is-the-difference-between-lowagie-and-itext)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see 3 questions. I will answer only 2 of them, for the third question you need to open a new topic on Stack Overflow.

These are your questions as I see them:

1. What is the difference between itext and itextpdf?
2. What am I missing in my dependency upgrade?
3. Why have my barcodes stopped working?

### 1. Difference between itext and itextpdf

tl;dr: **there is no difference!**

I would also like to refer you to these duplicate questions:

- [Difference between com.lowagie.text and iText 2.1.7 JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352843/difference-between-com-lowagie-text-and-itext-2-1-7-jar)
- [What is the difference between lowagie and iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515210/what-is-the-difference-between-lowagie-and-itext)

Longer answer:

iText is a PDF library for Java which was originally developed by Bruno Lowagie. You can still see that in the old versions of iText (prior to 5.0.0), the packages are called `com.lowagie.*` Some years ago, Bruno Lowagie founded a company around his iText product, **iText Software**. At the time the domain name `itext.com` was not available, so he registered [itextpdf.com](http://itextpdf.com). Starting from version 5.0.0, the package names were renamed from `com.lowagie.*` to `com.itextpdf.*`. It is a common practice to name your packages after the reverse of your domain name.

As a crude rule of thumb:

- Versions 1.x.x and 2.x.x = `com.lowagie.*` = developed by Bruno Lowagie
- Versions 5.x.x and 7.x.x = `com.itextpdf.*` = developed by iText Software
- Versions 4.x.x = released by someone unknown, unrelated to iText Software. Not an official release. Do not use.

### 2. What is missing in the dependency upgrade

- Only use version 5.5.10.
- Delete all other versions.
- Check your code for `import com.lowagie` and replace with `import com.itextpdf`.
- Fix any compilation errors.

### 3. Why have your barcodes stopped working

I don't know. Open a new topic on Stack Overflow and add enough code so anyone can reproduce your issue. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)